# rosbridge_suite: InvalidPackageException: Unable to load the manifest for package rosgraph_msgs

Tags: ros, rosbridge, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the rosbridge internal library to get load the message class for a given message type:

```
from rosbridge_library import ros_loader
...
self.msg_class = ros_loader.get_message_class(self.msg_type)
```

where self.msg_type is, for example, "rosgraph_msgs/Log".

This is generating the following error:

```
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbridge_library/internal/ros_loader.py", line 88, in get_message_class
    return _get_msg_class(typestring)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbridge_library/internal/ros_loader.py", line 128, in _get_msg_class
    return _get_class(typestring, "msg", _loaded_msgs, _msgs_lock)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbridge_library/internal/ros_loader.py", line 163, in _get_class
    cls = _load_class(modname, subname, classname)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbridge_library/internal/ros_loader.py", line 187, in _load_class
    raise InvalidPackageException(modname, exc)
InvalidPackageException: Unable to load the manifest for package rosgraph_msgs. Caused by: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
<Greenlet at 0x7f1c3cc52230: <bound method RosGraphApi.launch_graph of <luxagent.ros_communication.ros_graph_api.RosGraphApi object at 0x7f1c3cc26090>>> failed with InvalidPackageException
```

This error is occurring on all message types, not just `rosgraph_msgs/Log`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Simon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233758/rosbridge_suite:-invalidpackageexception:-unable-to-load-the-manifest-for-package-rosgraph_msgs./) by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2016-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) on 2016-05-06**:
I'm running on Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This turned out not to be a problem with rosbridge_library at all, but a collateral effect of using **gevent** in my application. It's highly unlikely that anyone else will come across this, but just in case:

I had to bury down into the depths of roslib to find out where the root exception was occurring. It was in rospkg/os_detect.py:

```
def _read_stdout(cmd):
    try:
        pop = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        (std_out, std_err) = pop.communicate()
        # Python 2.6 compatibility
        if isinstance(std_out, str):
            return std_out.strip()
        return std_out.decode(encoding='UTF-8').strip()
    except:
        return None
```

The line **pop.communicate()** was giving an error **'module' object has no attribute 'poll'**.

This led me here: https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/gevent/IzWhGQHq7n0

**gevent** is a coroutine based sort-of-multitasking library. It monkey patches various system libraries (I should have known better!) and removes the **poll()** functionality from subprocesses.

The solution is to import gevent like so:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all(aggressive=False)
```

instead of:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

My apologies to Jihooni for taking up his time! Thanks again.

---

Originally posted by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) with karma: 88 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-10**:
+1 for reporting back on the real cause (and a possible work-around).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like rosgraph_msgs is not detect in your ros package path. Make sure that correct ros environment is set in the PC.
It cannot find message packages without proper ROS_PACKAGE_PATH setup.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2016-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) on 2016-05-07**:
Here's my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:

```
/home/simonbirrell/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

This is created when I do the following before running my app:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Is there anything obvious missing?

**Comment by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) on 2016-05-07**:
Tried

```
rospack find rosgraph_msgs

/opt/ros/indigo/share/rosgraph_msgs
```

Which suggests that ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is ok.

Thanks for the help, Jihooni! Any further ideas appreciated.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2016-05-09**:
Or can you try

http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_message_converter